# I am receiving null, when do a post from Vue/NuxtJs

Tags: .net, axios, nuxt.js

I am getting null when I tried to post an image from Vue/Nuxt to .net Core 2.1

Could do check what is wrong with my code?

Front End

```
async saveImage({
    commit
  }, files) {

    let signage = await this.$axios.$post(
      "http://localhost:56980/api/PlanImages/", {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }, files).then((response) => {
      alert(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
};
```

Backend

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post( IFormFile files)
    {
        var result = await UploadPhotosBucket.UploadPhoto(files);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Ok(new { result.FileName });
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(_constants.RecordNotCreated());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue, can not get a [frombody] parameter in the API.
Even simple strings. It works from postman, not from axios.
Someone smart, please figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This **github repo** might be helpful for you [ASP.NET Core **FileUpload** with **Vue.JS** & **Axios**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deanilvincent/ASP-NET-Core-FileUpload-with-VueJS-Axios/master/Images/aspnetcorefileuploadwithaxiosandvue.gif)

Basically, he used the **IFormCollection** files instead of **IList** files

Comment: Thanks, but I am only what to send one file, and look like there is something wrong either my vue or .net core backend

Comment: You can try some other approach like using form data (multipart/form-data), It means send files using simple form action on the client-side and check if your back-end endpoint works well or not. If the test was OK you can check the Vue.js project to find out what the problem is.